# What are the breaking changes in Elastic Search 1.7.5?

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I am upgrading elastic search and NEST to 1.7.x.
I have found this link https://nest.azurewebsites.net/breaking-changes.html but it doesn't have complete information.Any other documents?

Comment: to 1.7.x? don't you mean to 2.x? https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/2.x/index.html new docs

Comment: and if you just want changes for 2.x https://www.elastic.co/blog/ga-release-of-nest-2-0-our-dot-net-client-for-elasticsearch

Answer (score 1):

Release notes for Elasticsearch 1.7.5 are available at

[elastic.co/downloads/past-releases/elasticsearch-1-7-5](https://www.elastic.co/downloads/past-releases/elasticsearch-1-7-5)

and for NEST 1.8.0 (the latest compatible with Elasticsearch 1.x)

[github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/releases/tag/1.8.0](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/releases/tag/1.8.0)

Also take a look at other releases in the 1.x branch (as 1.8.0 was simply a bump of the dependency on Json.Net to major version 8)

[github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/releases](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/releases)